# How to I update to the latest wallet version (0.8.3) on Windows 10?

Tags: windows

I've been using Ethereum for a while and have quite a bit invested so I think it would be wise to update to the latest version. I visited the GitHub page and downloaded the latest Windows installer and found that all it does is open up an un-synced Ethereum wallet on the latest version, without any of my wallets, etc. How do I go about updating the wallet properly and safely?

Answer (score 1):

in the Mist [doc](https://github.com/ethereum/mist), it is indicated that :

> For updating simply download the new version and copy it over the old
>   one (keep a backup of the old one if you want to be sure). The data
>   folder for Mist is stored in other places:
>
> Windows %APPDATA%\Mist